# How can i invoke on-demand background service running on gcp app engine without using http?

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a background service on google cloud platform app engine.
Service is using generic host to schedule the task now i want to run the service on demand, so what are the possible ways to do this?
Can i achieve this using google pub/sub?

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using Google Cloud Functions: https://cloud.google.com/functions/. Google Cloud Functions (GCF) is a lightweight compute solution for developers to create single-purpose, stand-alone functions that respond to Cloud events without the need to manage a server or runtime environment. You can use a Background Function that is triggered by a Cloud Pub/Sub message. For more details, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub.